# Character counts do not add up in Java

Tags: java

I am writing a Java program that goes through a file and provides counts of characters. The problem I'm having is that my counts aren't adding up. When I add the `isAlphabetic(char c)` and `isDigit(char c)`, they do not equal the `isLetterOrDigit(char c)` method (please forgive me if I'm using the wrong terminology).

What am I missing? Here is a copy of my code so far.

```
for (String word : words) {
                char[] ch = word.toCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                    if (Character.isBmpCodePoint(ch[i])) {
                        charCount++;
                        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch[i])) {
                            alphnumCount++;
                        }
                        if (Character.isAlphabetic(ch[i])) {
                            alphabetCount++;
                        }
                        if (Character.isDigit(ch[i])) {
                            numericCount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Reading next line into currentLine
            currentLine = reader.readLine();
        }
        // Printing charCount, wordCount and lineCount
        System.out.println("Number Of Chars In..Lab.docx File : " + charCount);
        System.out.println("Number Of Alph+Numeric Chars In..Lab.docx File : " + alphnumCount);
        System.out.println("Number Of Alphabet Chars In..Lab.docx File : " + alphabetCount);
        System.out.println("Number Of Numeric Chars In..Lab.docx File : " + numericCount);
        System.out.println("Number Of Words In..Lab.docx File : " + wordCount);
        System.out.println("Number Of Lines In..Lab.docx File : " + lineCount);
        System.out.println(alphabetCount + numericCount - alphnumCount);

        reader.close(); // Closing the reader
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Note: The `  ` formatting only works for single lines, to format your code you must highlight it and click the `{}` button on the editor. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to edit it now? From my end, it looks correctly formatted now.

Comment: No, the formatting should be fine now. Just letting you know for next time. : )

Comment: did you ever check whether the input text is read correctly? Lines, words, chars? Did you ever use a debugger?

Comment: No, I did not check whether the input text is read correctly. I converted my *.docx to a plain text file and the numbers add up, as suggested below. For some reason, a Word document adds 105 characters between the isDigit and isAlphabet vs. the isLetterOrDigit. My assignment is to find the missing 105 characters and to show them in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Problem here is that you are reading an `*.docx` file.

If I use a simple text file with the following content your script works.

```
Test123
7asdf
```

The output is:

```
Number Of Chars In..CSCI_1136_Lab6.docx File : 12
Number Of Alph+Numeric Chars In..CSCI_1136_Lab6.docx File : 12
Number Of Alphabet Chars In..CSCI_1136_Lab6.docx File : 8
Number Of Numeric Chars In..CSCI_1136_Lab6.docx File : 4
Number Of Words In..CSCI_1136_Lab6.docx File : 2
Number Of Lines In..CSCI_1136_Lab6.docx File : 2
0
```

If you want to count the characters in a `*.docx` file that is not possible in this way, because you are interpreting the bytes of that file as String, which they don't are.

> DOCX is written in an XML format, which consists of a ZIP archive file containing XML and binaries.

From [forensicswiki](https://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Word_Document_(DOCX)).

So `*.docx` files are not stored in plain text, which you are expecting in your code.

Another point is that you are using `Character.isAlphabetic()` instead of `Character.isLetter()`:

Form the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic(int)) for `Character.isAlphabetic()`:

> Determines if the specified character (Unicode code point) is an alphabet.
>
> A character is considered to be alphabetic if its general category type, provided by getType(codePoint), is any of the following:
>
> - UPPERCASE_LETTER
> - LOWERCASE_LETTER
> - TITLECASE_LETTER
> - MODIFIER_LETTER
> - OTHER_LETTER
> - LETTER_NUMBER
>
> or it has contributory property Other_Alphabetic as defined by the Unicode Standard.

Form the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(int)) for `Character.isLetter()`:

> Determines if the specified character (Unicode code point) is a letter.
>
> A character is considered to be a letter if its general category type, provided by Character.getType(ch), is any of the following:
>
> - UPPERCASE_LETTER
> - LOWERCASE_LETTER
> - TITLECASE_LETTER
> - MODIFIER_LETTER
> - OTHER_LETTER
>
> Not all letters have case. Many characters are letters but are neither uppercase nor lowercase nor titlecase.

So there is a difference between both methods. The method `Character.isLetterOrDigit()` is using `isLetter()` and `isDigit()`;

> Determines if the specified character (Unicode code point) is a letter or digit.
>
> A character is considered to be a letter or digit if either isLetter(codePoint) or isDigit(codePoint) returns true for the character.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(int)) for `Character.isLetterOrDigit()`.

So if you use `Character.isLetter()` instead of `Character.isAlphabetic()` your result should be correct.

This is my result for a `*.docx` file using `Character.isLetter()`:

```
Number Of Chars In..CSCI_1136_Lab6.docx File : 5923
Number Of Alph+Numeric Chars In..CSCI_1136_Lab6.docx File : 1758
Number Of Alphabet Chars In..CSCI_1136_Lab6.docx File : 1550
Number Of Numeric Chars In..CSCI_1136_Lab6.docx File : 208
Number Of Words In..CSCI_1136_Lab6.docx File : 66
Number Of Lines In..CSCI_1136_Lab6.docx File : 48
0
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, I have to use the *.docx file. It's part of my assignment. I'm just trying to figure out why there is an extra 105 characters when I total the isAlphabetic and isDigit compared to the isLetterOrDigit methods.

Comment: @darkrabb1t You should use `Character.isLetter()` instead of `Character.isAlphabetic()`. I updated my answer to explain it a bit more.

Comment: Phillip, I am going with your recommendation and will provide the explanation you gave regarding the DOCX being written in XML format. Hopefully, it is what my professor is looking for. His instructions were to show the missing characters within the code. My final code included using 'Character.isLetter()' and 'Character.isAlphabetic()' with that one commented out. Thank you!!